# MySQL Left Join with no matches on Table B, has no ID on Table A

Tags: mysql, join

I try doing somethin like this:

Table A

```
NameID | name | other rows
1      | name1
2      | nameA
3      | nameX
```

Table B

```
UniqueID | NameID | other rows
1        | 1
2        | 2
3        | 6
4        | 17
5        | 22
```

No I want to do a select like this:

```
SELECT tablea.ID, tablea.name, tableb.*
            FROM tablea
            LEFT JOIN tableb ON tablea.ID = tableb.ID
            WHERE
            tablea.ID != '0'
```

I search now for the ID and the name.

I get allways the name, but not allways the ID, only if the ID is in table B also. why?

My result is like this:

```
ID   | name
1    | name1
2    | nameA
NULL | nameX
```

I have this situation:
I have in TABLE A films (with names, datas, etc.). In table B I have 
ratings of these movies. Now I search with a form and want to see all movies, that have an incomplete rating, or no ratings at all, or any film despite of it has or not ratings.

With a LEFT JOIN on TABLE A (all movies) and with the addition ON-Condition I search if the movie has a rating or not (is or is not in TABLE B).
My result get me the name of the movie, allways. But if the movieID is not in table B (= no ratings recorded), I do not get the ID of the Movie in table A in the result.
So not my entire result is NULL only the movieID, I can pull any other DATA out of TABLE A for this movie, but not the ID.

so why?

Is it not possible to ask for the tablea.ID, if the ID is in the ON - term?

Comment: the WHERE is converting the LEFT JOIN into a INNER JOIN.. you should move the WHERE statement to the ON clause

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that the WHERE is for tablea and the ON is for the tableb I conbine it with? How can the WHERE transform the LEFT Join to a INNER JOIN?

Comment: what `ID` are you joining on in `tablea.ID = tableb.ID` ? `NameID` ?/

Comment: @RaymondNijland the condition is of `TABLE A` and that is the main table used in the query.

Comment: @BhavikPatel the NameID. Am I able to say explicit which table to be used, by selecting the ID? like :        
            $queryrequest = $reseachSBS->tablea.nameID;   ?

Comment: yes, in your code you have to specify, can you alias the column in your select and try ?

Comment: That was the right Answer. I had to alias the column name, now it works. The point is, that if I have multiple rows, with the same name, he will take the last row, that was mentioned for the mysql_fetch_object. In my case this represents NULL, becuase it was not in table b. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, to set an alias for the row in table one, which is duplicated in the second table and has due to no "rows" in second table the outcome NULL.
If I put an alias into it, I can select it and LEFT JOIN will do the rest.

What to know: mysql_fetch_object will always select the last mention of a row, if the row name is identic in other tables of the select. In my case I LEFT JOIN a second table with the same row-name. Due to LEFT JOIN I have no results on the ON condition and the correct outcome for my query is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Left join will show all rows form the first table and add data from the second table when a matching rows is found.
If no matching row is found, left join will return null (which means "unknown") for those rows.
If you want to discard rows from you result that have no matching row in the other table, you have to use "inner join" instead of "left join".
Check visual representation of joins for more info: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: I try to explain it better.

I have in totally 3 tables and a form, where I can use dropdowns to select, what I search out of this tables. I have a code, that put it JOIN CONDITIONS into this select and WHERE CONDITIONS. 

So it may happen, that sometimes, I do not want to search in tableb anything, so I have to select ALL out of this table. So I need LEFT JOIN. The Problem is, that I get the name out of table A but not the ID out of the same ROW in same TABLE A. 

I think that is, because my left join is ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID ... and it may be no match in table B.